# Error: 'tuple' is not callable in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Getting a type error, 'tuple' object is not callable. Any idea what it could be? I am trying to create a program for steganography using DCT.

```
def write_to_image(path, text):
    img = Image.open(path)
    img.getdata()
    r, g, b = [np.array(x) for x in img.split()]
    lx, ly = r.shape() #Error is here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lx, ly = r.shape
```

shape will not have ()

Answer (score 1):

As written [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html): the `shape` attribute of a Numpy array is an attribute, not a method, and is a tuple.

Try `lx, ly = r.shape`.

Note that I'm not calling `r.shape`, I'm just accessing it like you would any other attribute of an object.